# Convert FASTA to FASTQ with dummy quality scores

Tags: fasta, fastq

I have a FASTA file which I would like to convert into FASTQ format as the tool I want to use my data in requires it in FASTQ format. So dummy quality scores are fine.

Note: I am not using any functionality of the tool that will require the quality score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this is with two subcommands from the [`pyfastaq`](https://github.com/sanger-pathogens/Fastaq) suite.

```sh
fastaq to_fake_qual in.fasta - | fastaq fasta_to_fastq in.fasta - out.fastq
```

The first tool, `to_fake_qual`, creates fake quality scores (default 40) for each base and the `-` sends that file (`.qual`) to stdout. The second tool, `fasta_to_fastq`, consumes both the original fasta and the quality scores coming from stdin and turns these into a fastq file.

Answer (score 6):

A simple Biopython solution:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for r in SeqIO.parse("myfile.fa", "fasta"):
    r.letter_annotations["solexa_quality"] = [40] * len(r)
    print(r.format("fastq"), end='')
```

Example:

```
$ cat << EOF > myfile.fa 
>1
ATG
>2
ATGTAGA
EOF
$ python3 myscript.py 
@1
ATG
+
III
@2
ATGTAGA
+
IIIIIII
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the python package [bioconvert](https://bioconvert.readthedocs.io/en/master/user_guide.html#explicit-conversion) does what you want if you don't provide qualities: https://github.com/bioconvert/bioconvert/blob/master/bioconvert/fasta2fastq.py

The following outputs lots of warnings for me, but does generate a fastq file `test.fq` from an existing fasta file `test.fa` (using dummy quality "I", and adding "None" to sequence headers that do not have a comment part in the original fasta):

```
bioconvert fasta2fastq test.fa test.fq
```

(This requires installing bioconvert using `pip` beforehand: `pip install bioconvert`.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick one-liner with no dependencies other than the UNIX core utils and Perl.

```
cat seqs.fasta | paste - - | perl -ne 'chomp; s/^>/@/; @v = split /\t/; printf("%s\n%s\n+\n%s\n", $v[0], $v[1], "B"x length($v[1]))' > seqs.fastq
```

Caveat: assumes your Fasta sequences are not wrapped, i.e. two lines per record.

Answer (score 0):

I have just uploaded a Python tool to convert fasta to fastq: https://github.com/Mostafa-MR/A_tool_to_convert_fasta_to_fastq

Please note this is presented directly from a Jupyter notebook, i.e. it is a ipynb.